# Node.js simple app doesn't get second get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to run very basic script as following:

```
import express from "express";

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.set("json spaces", 4);

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({status: "NTask API"}));

app.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    tasks: [
      {title: "Buy some shoes"},
      {title: "Fix notebook"}
    ]
  });
});
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`NTask API - Port ${PORT}`));
```

the results are:

> {
>       "status": "NTask API" }

My question is, why the tasks is not there? 
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the expected result? How do you make the requests?

Comment: The expected results are: { "tasks": [ {"title" "Buy some shoes"}, {{"title" "fix notebbook"} ] }

Comment: You are getting the results for a request to `/`.  If you want the tasks, you have to request `/tasks`.  If you have a problem with that part, then show us the code that makes the request.

Comment: I missed that... I just copied the code from guide and it skipped the part of request /tasks. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it turned out to be the solution.

You are getting the results for a request to `/`. If you want the tasks, you have to request `/tasks`.